Caulk to Reduce Neighbor Floor Creaking?
I recently moved into an apartment, the building is very old and has hardwood flooring. When my nextdoor neighbor (who I share a wall with) is walking, I can very audibly hear the creaking of his floor. there is about a 1/4 inch gap between the floors and the bottom of the wall, I don't know anything about this topic, But would filling the gap with caulk Stabilize the floors and reduce sound transmission between us?

I never encountered this kind of issue, but I would say trying to caulk should not make the situation worse.

I doubt it would help, since the sound is probably being transmitted through the floor. But I can't see that it would hurt...

test by jamming some paper into the gap ... rolled up paper towel would be the easiest

The creak is not caused by the gap and will sound through the boards especially if they connect through the rooms.

Agree with some of the other comments. Caulk will do nothing.
